# Attempting to search database through PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I've written some code to search a database for whatever is entered, however it just shows a white screen. I'm still quite unsure with using OO, so maybe it's the query? I've tried several different ways of this but same white screen. Must be something obvious just need another pair of eyes.

The connection to the database works fine so it's not an issue there and the $POST value is correct.

**Search.php**

```
<?php 
session_start();
include 'searchform.php'
include 'pagetemplate.php';
if(isset($_POST['searchsubmit'])){
        $name=$_POST['name'];
                if ($stmt = $connection->prepare ("SELECT * FROM users WHERE FirstName LIKE ? OR LastName LIKE ? OR Username LIKE ?")) 
                {
                $stmt->bind_param('sss', $name, $name, $name);
                $stmt->execute();
                $stmt->bind_result($personresult);
                $stmt->fetch();
                printf($personresult);
                } 
                else
                { 
                echo  "<p>Please enter a search query</p>"; 
                } 
            } 
        } 

    ?>
```

Comment: white screen usually means syntax errors

Comment: add an `else{ echo "not set"; }` to `if(isset($_POST['searchsubmit'])){...}` if you see that, you'll know what to go after. same for the other POST array.

Comment: OR.... [searchsubmit] is not actually set? So just skipping that code block?

Comment: Echo'd out both but still white screen and no writing.
@AdamJeffers it's named searchsubmit in the form and the value is Submit, so I can't see how it's not being set

Comment: are you seeing "Please enter a search query" by any chance?

Comment: there... it's a syntax error and error reporting would've thrown you that (unexpected end of file...). IF...that's your real/full code.

Comment: If you really want `like` put in percents otherwise it is the same as `=`.

Comment: Not seeing any error no Fred, like: '%?%' - is this the right format?

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, and you will.

Comment: Still no errors displaying, just white screen

Comment: then `$stmt->execute();` to `if(!$stmt->execute()){trigger_error("there was an error....".$connection->error, E_USER_WARNING);}`

Comment: Still nothing, refusing to show any errors!

Comment: time to `var_dump();` then.

Comment: Get error reporting working - before you sort that out anything else is just guesswork

Comment: I'll bet my last dollar, if you change `printf($personresult);` to either `print` or `echo` or `print_r`, you'll see something. The manual http://php.net/manual/en/function.printf.php states `printf("%d", "17,999")` so it's looking for a special argument. That's why you're not getting anything "shown on screen"/ouput.

Comment: Nope, still nothing mate, tried that before when i thought printf was screwing it up

Comment: @Fred-ii- I think only the first argument to printf is required. If you don't include any placeholders in the format string, it works just like print. Like a weird, unnecessary print, but still.

Comment: @Don'tPanic thanks, but I've given up on the question.

Answer (score 0):

You have an extra `}`, try this instead...

```
<?php 
session_start();
include 'searchform.php'
include 'pagetemplate.php';
if(isset($_POST['searchsubmit']))
{
        $name=$_POST['name'];

        if ($stmt = $connection->prepare ("SELECT * FROM users WHERE FirstName LIKE ? OR LastName LIKE ? OR Username LIKE ?")) 
        {
            $stmt->bind_param('sss', $name, $name, $name);
            $stmt->execute();
            $stmt->bind_result($personresult);
            $stmt->fetch();
            printf($personresult);
        } 
        else
        { 
            echo  "<p>Please enter a search query</p>"; 
        } 
} else
     echo "NOT SET!";

?>
```

Comment: Cheers mate, tried this but same as before just returning a white screen

Comment: I was convinced that was it as well.

Comment: Tried all sorts of things to sort it out but just get this! Refusing to show any errors too